# Marlin Firmware troubles: <time.h> error

Tags: arduino-mega, firmware

I am trying to upload the Marlin Firmware to my 3D printer's Arduino Mega 2560 and I am experiencing a problem. It keeps saying:

```
qr_solve.cpp:7:18: fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory
 #include <time.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Error compiling.
```

Please help as I'm lost as how to fix it, because I try to scroll up to see what is highlighted in red and I can't find anything.

Comment: This might be helpful; https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/deltabot/IknX0wamH2M

Comment: Gerben's comment fixed my issue.

Comment: Hi @Rdawg33 - If one of the answers below solved your issue, can you mark it as the accepted answer, using the tick icon next to the answer, in order to remove your question from the [Unanswered Questions](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [Gerben's link](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18893/marlin-firmware-troubles#comment35188_18893) to the googlegroups's thread, [Delta robot 3D printers › compiling jcrocholl's Marlin (Ubuntu)](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/deltabot/IknX0wamH2M), as Francis Mallet points out, at the [bottom of the thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/deltabot/IknX0wamH2M/pIffvuv1CEYJ), it is necessary to change `<time.h>` to `"Time.h"`:

> I copied the content of the Time library right in the Marlin folder, then changed line 7 of qr_solve.cpp from #include  to #include "Time.h"
>
> The code compiled and everything seems to be working ok.

So, to iterate, the line in `qr_solve.cpp`:

```
#include <time.h>
```

becomes

```
#include "Time.h"
```

Now, `Marlin.ino` should compile as expected.

Note that the latest version of Marlin, from [github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin) no longer suffers from this issue, but older versions of the software, such as [github.com/gpfwestie/kossel_2020_sintron](https://github.com/gpfwestie/kossel_2020_sintron) will do, due to [line 7, in `qr_solve.cpp`](https://github.com/gpfwestie/kossel_2020_sintron/blob/master/Marlin-deltabot%20for%20Sintron%20Kossel%20mini/Marlin/qr_solve.cpp#L7).

Answer (score -1):

interestingly changing to Time.h didn't work for me (arduino sdk 1.6.9) however commenting out the include line did...